# Why doesn't the JOSE suite/JWA include ECIES?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, ecies, jwe, jose

The JOSE suite specifics use of RSA-OAEP (for when one party has an RSA key) and ECDH (for when two parties have EC keys) in JWA.

Why doesn't it include ECIES? It seems like a way to derive a key when only one party has an EC key would be a common need.

Comment: I've created the language tags, thanks for the heads up. Feel free to make tag edit suggestions.

Comment: Probably because JOSE is a disorganized garbage pit of whatever acronym soup the authors had heard of and saw fit to dump in, and they hadn't heard of ECIES?  Generally my approach to JOSE and JWT is to run away screaming from the incoherent security goals and attacker-controlled interpretation of everything…